# How to run batch class

Tags: apex

How can I do to run this class anonymously, it is showing an error every time I try to run.

Class batch:

```
public class TransferQueueCallout implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {
// instance member to retain state across transactions
public Integer recordsProcessed = 0;
public String Email; 
public String Inscription_Number; 

public TransferQueueCallout(String Email, String Inscription_Number){
    this.Email = Email; 
    this.Inscription_Number = Inscription_Number; 
}

public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
    return Database.getQueryLocator('SELECT Id, Email__c, Inscription_Number__c FROM Repository__c WHERE CreatedDate = Today');        
}    

public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<sObject> scope){  
    Integer size = scope.size(); 
    for(Integer i = 0; i < size; i++){
        String recordId = (String)scope.get(i).get('Id'); 
        ChangeEmailAPI.CallChangeEmailAPI(Email, Inscription_Number);
    }
    recordsProcessed = recordsProcessed + 1;
}


public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){
    System.debug(recordsProcessed + ' records processed.');
    AsyncApexJob job = [SELECT Id, Status, NumberOfErrors,
                        JobItemsProcessed,
                        TotalJobItems, CreatedBy.Email
                        FROM AsyncApexJob
                        WHERE Id = :bc.getJobId()];
    // call some utility to send email
    EmailUtils.sendMessage(job, recordsProcessed);
} }
```

I tried to anonymously execute this code:

```
TransferQueueCallout myBatchObject = new TransferQueueCallout(new Set<Id>);
Id batchId = Database.executeBatch(myBatchObject);
```

Error message:

```
Line: 1, Column: 22
Unexpected token 'myBatchObject'.
```

Answer (score 3):

```
TransferQueueCallout myBatchObject = new TransferQueueCallout(new Set<Id>);
```

Your class does not have a constructor that accepts `Set<Id>`. Your constructor accepts two parameters:

```
String Email, String Inscription_Number
```

Further, `new Set<Id>` isn't valid syntax; you'd have to write `new Set<Id>()`. Syntax errors can cause the compiler to return errors that don't obviously make sense.

Note that you will also have to implement the `Database.Stateful` marker interface to retain state across batch invocations.

Answer (score 2):

You have defined constructor of the class `TransferQueueCallout` with two parameters `String Email, String Inscription_Number`, but you have initilized with one `new TransferQueueCallout(new Set<Id>);`

This will throw compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to execute the class as follows:

```
TransferQueueCallout myBatchObject = new TransferQueueCallout();
Id batchId = Database.executeBatch(myBatchObject);
```

Comment: You added a default constructor?

Comment: This would never work given your piece of code above. And moreoever this is incorrect because your `Email` and `Inscription_Number` will be always null.

Answer (score 0):

I made some modifications to the class, and with these lines of code I was able to execute the class:

Revised class:

```
    public class TransferQueueCallout implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.AllowsCallouts, Database.Stateful {
    // instance member to retain state across transactions
    public set<ID> finalaccounts = new set<Id>();
    public Integer recordsProcessed = 0;
    
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator('SELECT Id, Email__c, Inscription_Number__c FROM Repository__c');  
    }    
    
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Repository__c> scope){  
        for(Repository__c cc:scope){
            finalaccounts.add(cc.Id);
            ChangeEmailAPI.CallChangeEmailAPI(cc.Email__c, cc.Inscription_Number__c);            
        } 
        recordsProcessed = recordsProcessed + 1;
    }
    
    
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){      
        System.debug('Registro(s) processado(s): ' + recordsProcessed + '.');        
        AsyncApexJob job = [SELECT Id, Status, NumberOfErrors,
                            JobItemsProcessed,
                            TotalJobItems, CreatedBy.Email
                            FROM AsyncApexJob
                            WHERE Id = :bc.getJobId()];
        // call some utility to send email
        EmailUtils.sendMessage(job, recordsProcessed);
    }
}
```

Running the class:

```
TransferQueueCallout myBatchObject = new TransferQueueCallout();
Id batchId = Database.executeBatch(myBatchObject);
```